# Binary strings and Onto functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, binary-operations

Let $B_3$ be the set of all binary strings of length $3$ and let $B_4$ be the set of all binary strings of length $4.$ There is at least one function $f : B_4 \to B_3$ that is onto. Is this true or not? Provide a proof either way.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function without any structure is easy to find:

All the ones in $B_4$ with the leftmost bit being $0$ are mapped to their respective pair

$$
0010\mapsto 010
$$

and the ones having a $1$ in the leftmost bit are mapped to $0$.

For structure preserving maps convert the strings into numbers in base $10$ to make it easier and modding by $8$ would make a map

$$
f:B_4\to B_3\qquad f(x)=[x]_8
$$
$[x]_8$ meaning the equivalence class modulo $8$.

Hope this helped

Comment: Note that your $f$ is defined directly on strings as $$f(b_4b_3b_2b_1) = b_3b_2b_1$$

Comment: it helped, but i am confused about : [x]8 meaning the equivalence class modulo 8, what does this mean? why did you choose 8?

Comment: since the target domain is $\mathbb{Z}_8$ and we would like to get an onto function

Comment: I mean it is not $\mathbb{Z}_8$ it is just a set with $8$ elements, but we can think about it as the integers modulo $8$

Comment: oh, thank you !